# Where can i find info generated by --dev flag? or is there a way to make it more verbose?

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Having an issue with testcafe/e2e tests - works fine in one containerized env, but fails in the other. Trying to debug/dig into what's wrong, but I only get a message of `ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.`

I am trying to use the `--dev` flag mentioned in the docs, but I don't get any more info - **my question is**: if there's somewhere extra logs are being written to I'm not aware of? Or is there any other way to make it more verbose so I can see what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [search TestCafe sources for developmentMode](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/search?q=developmentMode&unscoped_q=developmentMode) you can see that this option [enables non-minified js files](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/f105949a8cf5de6ddc27fa51fb2e94eccc298824/src/load-assets.js#L14), so you can step through debugger in your browser.

Since your problem is connecting to the browser, I guess this option won't help you.

Comment: thanks. yeah. looks like I'll have to dig through the libs, add some logging statements to try to see how far things get.

Answer (score 3):

As Roman mentioned, the `--dev` flag enables non-minified files. You can debug the code yourself using the `--dev` flag. Here is the code which leads to the error: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/f1d3ae38eedbd2b7e43869971c3705d76bb7fc36/src/runner/browser-set.js#L83

You'll find the compiled code in the `node_modules/testcafe/lib/runner/browser-set.js` file.

It looks like the browser does not respond in acceptable time.

Could you reproduce the issue stably? Could you reproduce it locally? We will appreciate it if you provide us with an example which will demonstrate the issue and allow us to debug it.

Comment: Thanks Alex! In the end, the issue was caused by that segfault bug in chromium. Upgrading to latest node-alpine and latest chromium solved the issue (this was in a kubernetes context, so the underlying host nodes we were using changed, which led to it spontaneously not working) https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/444#issuecomment-454383879

Comment: Is there any possible way for testcafe to provide more information than this? I experience the same error but inconsistently. There literally isn't a way for me to reproduce it consistently. Even if I could give you my whole project, I suspect my computer plays a role and it wouldn't work the same way on another. I understand the problem is probably on chrome's end, but is there any way to turn on chrome logging or call headless chrome the same way testcafe does?

Comment: PS, everything is running locally, including the browsers. Windows system.